# SmartEdit : Changes in nested CMS Component are not reflecting until unless refresh the page

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

SAP Commerce 1811

I created one custom CMS component which has collection of CMSlinkComponent assigned. Whenever i changed something in nested CMSLinkComponent and click on Save button in Child Editor, parent editor Save button is not getting enabled and if I cancel the parent editor, link changes are not getting reflected until unless i refresh the page again.

Is it a existing bug in SmartEdit ? or I am missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it related to ECP-4993 "Smartedit: Nested Component, refresh in storefront"? https://cxjira.sap.com/browse/ECP-4493

> Description:
>
> - We have seen that when editing nested components SmartEdit only refreshes the component if the parent component is changed. However,
>   if only children components are modified then no automatic update is
>   performed by SmartEdit
> - This forces the customer to manually refresh the page.
>
> AC:
>
> - When editing, the component in the storefront needs to be refreshed if at least one of the children components (regardless of the level of
>   nesting) is modified.
> - Fix must work in 2005. Backporting tickets need to be created as subtasks.

If it is, it's fixed in 1811.22: https://cxjira.sap.com/browse/PATCH-6795